# Semáforo con Hilos en Java

Tags: java, hilos, pipe

No consigo obtener el orden esperado... Creo que debo introducir condicionales en el interior del `while` de los metodos `encenderLuz()` y `apagarLuz()`

Resultado esperado...

```
ROJO ENCENDIDO
ROJO APAGADO
VERDE ENCENDIDO
VERDE APAGADO
AMBAR ENCENDIDO
AMBAR APAGADO
ROJO ENCENDIDO
ROJO APAGADO
etc... hasta final del bucle en run() de clase Luz
```

Codigo:

Clase Circuito (Tuberia)

```
public class Circuito {

    private boolean rojo = false;
    private boolean ambar = false;
    private boolean verde = false;
    private boolean todoApagado;

    private String anteriorLuz = "";

    public synchronized void apagarLuz(String luz){

        //Esperamos mientras no haya nada que apagar.
        todoApagado = rojo == false && ambar == false && verde == false;

        while(todoApagado){

            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Circuito.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }

        //Apagamos la luz.
        switch(luz){

            case "Rojo":
                rojo = false;
                break;

            case "Ambar":
                ambar = false;
                break;

            case "Verde":
                verde = false;
                break;

            default: 
                System.out.println("error");

        }      

        System.out.println(luz + " APAGAR -- Estado Rojo:" + rojo + " - Estado Ambar:" + ambar + " - Estado Verde:" + verde);
        anteriorLuz = luz;
        notify();

    }


    public synchronized void encenderLuz(String luz){

        //Esperamos mientras haya alguna encendida. (Y SI HAY MAS DE UNA....¿?¿?¿)
        while(rojo || ambar || verde){
            try {

                wait();

            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Circuito.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }

        if(luz.equals("Rojo")){
            rojo = true;
        }

        if(luz.equals("Ambar")){
            ambar = true;   
        }

        if(luz.equals("Verde")){
            verde = true;   
        }

        System.out.println(luz + " ENCENDER -- Estado Rojo:" + rojo + " - Estado Ambar:" + ambar + " - Estado Verde:" + verde);

        notify();

       }

    }
```

Clase Luz

```
//No se puede tocar la clase.
public class Luz extends Thread{

    private Circuito miCircuito;

    public Luz(String nombre, Circuito miCircuito){

        this.setName(nombre);
        this.miCircuito = miCircuito;

    }

    @Override
    public void run(){

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            miCircuito.encenderLuz(this.getName());
            miCircuito.apagarLuz(this.getName());

            //System.out.println("");
        }


    }

}
```

Clase Principal

```
//No se puede tocar la clase.
public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Circuito miCircuito = new Circuito();

        Luz rojo = new Luz("Rojo", miCircuito);
        Luz ambar = new Luz("Ambar", miCircuito);
        Luz verde = new Luz("Verde", miCircuito);

        rojo.start();
        ambar.start();
        verde.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Porfa, agrega el resultado que obtenes tambien

Comment: ¿La clase "Luz" no puedes modificarla?

Comment: ¿Lo dices Dani para agregar el estado de la luz a la clase Luz? Para eso supongo que si se podría. Lo intentare así, a ver si me facilita el algoritmo.

Answer (score 1):

yo supongo que lo que necesitas es que cada foco tenga su tiempo para encenderce

```
public class Circuito {
private boolean enchufe = false;
public synchronized void apagarLuz(String luz){
    System.out.println(luz + " Apagado");
    enchufe = false;
    notifyAll();
    try{
        wait();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}


public synchronized void encenderLuz(String luz){
    while(enchufe){
        try{
            wait();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    enchufe = true;
    System.out.println(luz + " encendido");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez es muy básico, pero no sirve poniendo un .join() a cada hilo, para que lo haga por orden?

```
rojo.start();
rojo.join();;
ambar.start();
ambar.join();
verde.start();
verde.join();
```

Answer (score 0):

Es difícil entender tus requisitos. Tal y como se encuentra el código en el estado actual, si lo que te propones es encender y apagar cada una de las luces una sola vez, bastaría con corregir la condición del bucle en el método run() de la clase Luz, cambiando 2 por 1. Pero esto parece demasiado sencillo como para ser realmente la respuesta que estás buscando...

```java
public class Luz extends Thread {

    // (...)

    @Override
    public void run(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            miCircuito.encenderLuz(this.getName());
            miCircuito.apagarLuz(this.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Salida:

```
Rojo  ENCENDER -- Estado Rojo:true  - Estado Ambar:false - Estado Verde:false
Rojo  APAGAR   -- Estado Rojo:false - Estado Ambar:false - Estado
Ambar ENCENDER -- Estado Rojo:false - Estado Ambar:true  - Estado Verde:false
Ambar APAGAR   -- Estado Rojo:false - Estado Ambar:false - Estado Verde:false
Verde ENCENDER -- Estado Rojo:false - Estado Ambar:false - Estado Verde:true
Verde APAGAR   -- Estado Rojo:false - Estado Ambar:false - Estado Verde:false
```

En el código tal y como lo has presentado, existe un grado de incertidumbre sobre el orden en el que se encenderán y apagarán las luces, un fenómeno (*non-determinism*) que seguro que ya sabes está asociado a la ejecución multihilo de aplicaciones y que puedes resolver mediante un abanico amplio de soluciones y mecanismos de control (bloqueos, semáforos, etc).

Comment: Hola, te sugerimos revisar: [CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido), saludos.